# How do I start Google Keep on Windows 8 startup

Tags: boot, google-chrome-extensions

I have this way of working on my computer: I usually have it started a little before I wake up by the BIOS so that when I wake up I have a fresh desktop with all the programs already open, since I put the applications I generally use on C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp (it's kind of a big deal since at any given time FF has dozens of tabs open). I would like to have Google Keep synced with the notes I usually take on the move on my smartphone but I can't find the .exe for Keep. The properties window of the Keep icon isn't of much help, I guess that's because it is a Chrome extension. Is there any way I can still make initialize together with the computer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right-click on the Keep icon in Chrome's App Launcher, then click "Create shortcuts..."

[image: create shortcuts context-click menu]

Create a desktop shortcut by checking "Desktop" and clicking "Create":

[image: create shortcuts dialog]

Finally, drag the newly-created shortcut into the `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` folder.

Alternatively, you can create a Start menu shortcut from the same dialog and then drag it into the Start menu's Startup folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make it as a native app by nativefier. You can download the wrapper I made here: https://github.com/ooker777/Web-wrapper

[image]